# Need help debugging invalid java node.js callback error message

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm

Need some help debugging the follwing. I put the errror message first then code snippet afterwards Its running

syedk@ubuntu:~$ node -v
v12.13.1
syedk@ubuntu:~$ npm -v
6.12.1
syedk@ubuntu:~

Error message

```
/var/www/html/code_drop/website/node_modules/formidable/lib/file.js:79:5)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:299:28)
at WriteStream.emit (events.js:210:5)
at finishMaybe (_stream_writable.js:656:14)
at _stream_writable.js:634:5
at WriteStream._final (internal/fs/streams.js:285:3)
at callFinal (_stream_writable.js:627:10)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
```

code: 'ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK'

---

snippet from file.js

```
File.prototype.end = function(cb) {
var self = this;
if (self.hash) {
self.hash =     self.hash.digest('hex');
}
this._writeStream.end(function()     {
self.emit('end');
cb();
```

Comment: This is JavaScript (the language specified as [ECMAScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript)). It is **not** Java. And has nothing to do with Java. Which is why the "official" name is ECMAScript (and **not** JavaScript).